# What can my work admin access on my devices signed in to a Google account?

Tags: windows-10, android, user-accounts

Seeing [this post](https://support.google.com/android/thread/52234320?hl=en) (“[Can we create multiple work profiles?](https://support.google.com/android/thread/52234320?hl=en)”) in Google’s Android support forum  I was kinda worried about how much organization know about me if I am signed in with a Google account from them (I mean even installed apps? & whether my phone is rooted or not? Come on!).

#### Android Phone

Technically my phone is Android and doesn’t have a work profile feature because of bad OEM ROM. Tried the [Shelter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter&hl=en_US) app but failed thanks to OEM. Phone is my own and not organization provided but “It would be better if I add that account to my phone for convenience.” Network I use is also mine and doesn’t use organizations gateway (ever)! There are no apps/extensions installed by organization on the phone.

#### Windows PC:

Laptop is mine, network is mine. No apps from organization are installed. Just signed in a Chrome profile with the account. I know already they have access to my web activity but what else?

If they have an enterprise account with highest privileges, what can they know about me?

Comment: Mobile phones are off topic here except insofar as the problem is in connecting to a computer. You should ask that part of your question at [android.se] and edit it out of your question here.